# JQuery .on not working when content is being called from Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-3

I've got an issue that I see was solved for many people, but it seems that none of the solutions are working for me.  Maybe it is my approach.

I've got an Edit page (for an `Album`), within, it has a `foreach` that inserts a `Partial View`.  The Edit page is meant to show a dynamic list of `Genre`s for that `Album`, it currently can add a new Drop Down (the Partial View), select and save (in the Controller).

I might want to add that this is MVC with Entity Framework utilizing JQuery 3.x

`Edit.cshtml` View (noting the `@foreach (var albumGenre in Model.AlbumGenres)` and later the Ajax link `@Ajax.ActionLink(`):

```
@model x.ViewModel.AlbumView
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @* Removing a bunch of code *@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumGenres, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div>
                    <table id="genres" style="border: 0px solid black;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var albumGenre in Model.AlbumGenres)
                        {
                            TempData["Genres"] = new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres, "Value", "Text", albumGenre.Genre.Oid);

                            //This is the PartialView
                            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Genres/_EditGenre.cshtml", albumGenre, ViewData)
                        }

                    </table>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10" style="float: right;">

                            // This calls the Controller = 
                            // public ActionResult AddNewGenre(Guid id) { return PartialView("~/Views/Genres/_EditGenre.cshtml", new AlbumsGenres(id)); }
                            @Ajax.ActionLink(
                                "Add Genre to Album",
                                "AddNewGenre", 
                                null,
                                new { id = Model.Oid },
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                                    UpdateTargetId = "genres"
                                },
                                new { style = "btn btn-info" }
                            )
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        @* Save button *@
    </div>
}

@* Next line is commented out as I need to run this script inside the _CreateGenre.cshtml (show further down in this question) *@
@* Hoping to load the JavaScript here so that it only needs to run once (not foreach Genre in the Album *@
@*<script src="~/Scripts/ContentPub/AddGenre.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

@* *@
```

From there I have the `_EditGenre.cshtml` view:

```
@model ContentPub.Models.Music.AlbumsGenres

@{ 
    if (TempData["Genres"] == null)
    {
        TempData["Genres"] = new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres, "Value", "Text", null);
    }

    TempData["ShowDisplay"] = false;
    TempData["BlankValue"] = "Select a Genre";
}

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("AlbumGenres"))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="GenreRow" class="form-group colorRow">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Oid)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Album.Oid)

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre.Oid, TempData["Genres"] as SelectList, TempData["BlankValue"] as String, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control genreDropDown" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre.Oid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div id="genreDialog" class="genreDialog"></div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <a class="button genreLink" href="@Url.Content("~/Genres/_Create")" id="genreAddLink_@Model.Oid">+</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


@* This needs to be active for the button to work, it looks like this: id="genreAddLink_@Model.Oid" *@
@* Also sad that it needs to be called for each Genre Partial View *@
<script src="~/Scripts/ContentPub/AddGenre.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@* *@
```

Below is my `AddGenre.js` script:

First the `.dialog` section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#genreDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Add Genre',

        buttons: {
            'Save': function () {
                // Removed for simplicity
            },

            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Then the `.on('click'...` section (this is what isn't being called when Ajax content is added to the page):

```
//$(document).ready(function () { //Tried with and without this

    // This is the old code that didn't work
    // $('.genreLink').on('click', function () { 

    //This is the supposive solution
    $('#GenreRow').on('click', '.genreLink', function () { // Also tried 'body' where '#GenreRow' is

        console.log("Clicked");
        var select = $(this).parent().parent().find('select');

        $('#genreDialog')
            .data("select", select)
            .dialog('open');

        var createFormUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#genreDialog').html('')

            .load(createFormUrl, function () {
                jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createGenreForm');
            });

        return false;

    });

//});
```

In short, I can open this Edit page, click the `+` to add a new Genre (in a Modal window), update all Drop Downs (and have the appropriate drop down get the new option selected) via JavaScript, happy with that.  However, I cannot click `Add Genre to Album` (Ajax call), then click the `+` next to the new Genre Drop Down, it navigates to `_CreateGenre` when I want it to open the Modal window (JavaScript/jQuery isn't firing).

The `$('#GenreRow').on('click', '.genreLink', function () {` isn't being fired and I don't know how to get it to do that. Another example, adding `console.log('JavaScript test');` will not fire when loading the content from the Partial View via Ajax.

Comment: _"Also tried 'body' where '#genreLink' is"_ `body` would go where `#GenreRow` is, not where `.genreLink` is

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I'll update, thank you

Comment: When and where is the .on being called? If you are calling the function before the ajax completes and adds the HTML to the page, it will not assign itself to the new HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#GenreRow` is being dynamically added by your partial view. When you run your javascript to attach a function to the click event for `.genreLink`, your `#GenreRow` may not have yet existed on your DOM at that time, so that would have no effect. And it looks like you are doing this when your DOM is ready (which I assume would be prior to your partial view being triggered/added to the DOM).

Try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.genreLink', function () {
   ...
}
```

Another option is to add a class to your *Add Genre* div:

```
<div class="AddGenreSection" class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10" style="float: right;">
      @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Genre to Album", ...)
   </div>
</div>
```

And since this div exists from the start (as it is part of your Edit.cshtml) you can attach the click event to that div like this:

```
$('.AddGenreSection').on('click', '.genreLink', function () {
   ...
}
```